# BPM 10.3 installation on clustered environment

Tags: business-process-management

I am executing a installation of BPM 10.3 on windows box. I have two windows boxes I need to run the BPM in cluster environment.

I have installed weblogic and BPM Server on my first window box, now I am confused if I will install BPM Server on Second window box. then how I will use the database schema for BPM Engine and directory service (what I have created while installing BPM Server on first box).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please precise the BPMS you're using ? It may be quiet different depending on the solution you're deploying.

Cheers